# What's the alternative for AMQP remoting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amqp, deprecated

We're using Spring AMQP in order to make RPC calls using Rabbitmq but AMQP remoting is removed in spring 6. What's the alternative for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Remoting with AMQP

> Spring remoting is no longer supported because the functionality has been removed from Spring Framework.

> Use sendAndReceive operations using the RabbitTemplate (client side ) and @RabbitListener instead.

They say in the [current document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#remoting). that is all I can find without seeing any code.